# Issues with nested for loops when calculating bond order for successive particle pairs

Tags: arrays, matlab, nested-for-loop

I wrote a short piece of code that pulls data from a few arrays that are created by a piece of code I was sent from my professor. The goal is to take the bond order parameter, **bR** in the workspace, paired with the location of the particle. From here I do the same with every other particle and multiply the bond orders together while calculating the distance between the two particles, location is taken from the center array. The second nested for loop averages the output from all of the particle pairs with the same distance between the particles which gives me the spatial correlation function for the particular solution. The issue I'm running into is that I should have something along the lines of:

[image: n(n-1)/2]     (n is the number of particles),

total distinct particle pairs(order doesn't matter) but I'm only getting n. This results in me only getting one total output when I should have a few thousand that I can plot. My previous coding experience is in c/c++ and I'm worried that I have coded something in the style of c that doesn't translate to Matlab. If anyone can give me a sanity check or some advice for coding this better I would appreciate it.

[image]

```
load('Psi6Data'); %%pulls data from bond order six movie

neighbor_distance = 0;
desire = 0;
sz = size(centers,1)*(size(centers,1)-1)/2;

array = double.empty;
array2 = double.empty;

for j = 1:size(centers,1) %%finds Psi6_a * Psi6_b as well as the distance between the two particles
    for p = (j+1):size(centers,1)
        neighbor_distance = sqrt((centers(p,1)-centers(j,1))^2/(centers(p,2)-centers(j,2))^2);
        desire = bR(1,j) * bR(1,p);
        array(j) = desire;
        array2(j) = neighbor_distance;
    end
end

sz2 = size(array);

output = double.empty; 
numerator = 0;
denominator = 0;
tempr = 0;

for k = 1:sz2 %% averaging to find g6r from each different instance of particle difference
    tempr = array2(k);
    output(k,2) = tempr;
    for n = 1:sz2
        if(array2(n) == tempr)
            numerator = numerator + array(n);
            denominator = denominator + 1;
        end
    end
    output(k,1) = numerator/denominator;
end
```

Comment: You assign into `array(j)`/`output(k,1)` for every iteration of the inner loop. (In both sets of nested for loops) It will overwrite the value many times.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!
I spot two problems:

1. you are changing the variables `array` and `array2` in the nested for-loop but assigning a value always to the same index (of the first loop). So you will get the same result if you simple cut the last loop and put `p=size(centers,1)`.

```
for j = 1:size(centers,1)
    for p = (j+1):size(centers,1)
        ...
        array(j) = desire; % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        array2(j) = neighbor_distance; % <<<<<<<<<<<<
    end
end
```

2. The variables `numerator` and `denominator` are initialized outside both loops and are manipulated inside the nested for-loop. This *may* result in undesired behavior, as they are net reset once the nested for-loop terminates. However, this is only a speculative flaw ;)

```
numerator = 0;
denominator = 0;

for k = 1:sz2
    for n = 1:sz2
        numerator = numerator + array(n);  % <<<<<
        denominator = denominator + 1; % <<<<<<<<<
    end
    output(k,1) = numerator/denominator;
end
```